# Is reciting Shema a mitzva d'oraisa?

Tags: shema, deorayta

The first paragraph of the Shema (itself from the Torah) includes the instruction to say the Shema twice daily "when we lie down and when we arise."
This would seem to indicate that the recitation of Shema is considered *d'oraisa*.

But the same paragraph instructs us to say these words "when we walk on the road and when we sit in our house."  We do not have a ritual to do either.
 This would seem to indicate that the recitation of Shema is rabbinic.

So, is reciting the Shema rabbinic or *d'oraisa*?
If d'oraisa, what don't we also adhere to the other directives mentioned in the paragraph?

Comment: [Brachot 21a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=21&format=pdf)

Comment: Regarding you ref to "When we sit in the house and walk in the road", Talmud Brachot concludes that these refer to the times of the day when we must say *Shema* and not that these become separate required *mitzvoth*. If it were, you'd never stop saying *Shema* as you would alternate these places several times per day, unless you're a hermit or a travelling salesperson.

Comment: @DanF  Where in Brachot, please?

Comment: Start with Brachot bottom of 10b (Mishnah) and continue w/ Gemarah on top of 11a. It explains the difference of opinions between Bet Shamai & Bet Hillel, but we follow Bet Hillel in this case.

Comment: See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77874/8775.

Comment: @DanF "When we sit in the house and walk in the road" refers to the **manner** in which one may say *Shema* (sitting, standing, etc.), not the times of the day when it must be said.

Comment: @Ploni Ach! I used the wrong terms! I meant the terms, "When we lie down and when we arise".

Answer (score 8):

Shulchan Aruch Harav ([OC 58:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=236)) brings three opinions as to which parts of *shema* are *d'oraisoh* (all the opinions he brings agree that at least some part is *d'oraisoh*):

> 1. R' Eliezer ([Berachos 21a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=21&format=pdf)) is of the opinion that **just the first paragraph** of *shema* is *d'oraisoh*.
> 2. The second opinion is that **also the second paragraph** of *shema* is *d'oraisoh* (רמב"ם פ"א מהל' ק"ש ה"א-ב, תוס' ברכות ב,א ד"ה מאימתי)
> 3. The third opinion is that **only the first *pasuk*** (i.e. שמע ישראל ה' אלקינו ה' אחד) is *d'oraisoh* (Rashba).

According to these opinions:

- "ובלכתך בדרך" teach us that *shema* may be said in any position (standing or sitting).
- "ובשכבך ובקומך" teaches us that *shema* is to be recited in the morning (when people get up) and at night (when people go to sleep).

The *gemara* ([Berachos 21a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=21&format=pdf)) brings the opinion of *Shmuel* who holds that reading *shema* is *d'rabanan*. He learns that "ובשכבך ובקומך" refers to the study of *Torah*.

Comment: Note Tosfot in two places seems to rule like Shmuel

Answer (score 2):

You ask:

> `But the same paragraph instructs us to say these words when we walk on the road and when we sit in our house. We do not have a ritual to do either.`

There are three opionions regarding Krias Shema:

.  **The first opinion** (and some Rishonim stated it for the halacha, as Tosfot quoted below) following which **even the first chapter's recitation is only a rabbinical mitzva**.

**Tosfot** [Sota 32a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.32a.5?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Sotah.32a.5.2&lang2=bi).

> וליכא למימר דלא נקט אלא דאורייתא דהא בפרק מי שמתו ([ברכות דף כא.](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.21a.7?lang=bi)) משמע דתפלה וקרית שמע דרבנן‏

> It seems from the Gemara, chapter Mi Shemmeto ([Brachot 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.21a.7?lang=bi)), that Kriat Shema is a rabbinical commandment.

The Gemara on Brachot 21a quoted by Tosfot asks your question against this opinion (Rav Yehuda amar Shmuel) for the words of the first chapter.

> The recital of the **Shema** is ordained only by the Rabbis, the saying of 'True and firm' אמת) ויציב) is a Scriptural ordinance.
> R' Joseph raised an objection to this, 'And when thou liest down, and when thou risest up'(ובשכבך ובקומך). Said Abaye to him: That was written with reference to words of Torah.

. But in this Gemara Berachot, there are two opinions regarding KS, **Rabbi Yehuda in name of Shmuel**, according to him KS is **derabanan**, which we talked about above, and the Amora **Rabbi Eleazar** (there are a couple of versions for this name), according to him it's scriptural, **Deorayta**.

. If KS is Deorayta, are the first two chapters a scriptural mitzvah or is only the first chapter a scriptural mitzvah?

See the question and its answer in Gemara Berachot 13b **regarding the second chapter** (in this question we assume that the first chapter is a scriptural mitsva):

> [Presumably] because it is written, 'upon thy heart and thou shalt speak of them? ' There too [in the second section] also it is written, 'upon your heart to speak.
> of them'! **These words have reference to words of Torah,**

So for the opinion following which the recitation of the second chapter (but not the first) is a Rabbinical Mitxva, the verse "thou shall speak them" tells to speak Divre Torah, not particularly this chapter reading.

---

Regarding the Poskim.
**Rif, Rambam, Rosh in halachot Brachot, Rashba, Tur and SA** ruled against Shmuel (contrarily to the Tosfot in Sota). And last Poskim (Acharonim) followed this opinion.

Rishonim argued about the lenght of what is **the stuff called KS** in Gemara Berachot 21a.

There are several opinions.

. Some Rishonim and Acharonim (**Tshuvat Harashba** 320, **Rabbi Yehuda Hachasid** in Tur OC  67, Bet Yosef, **Magen Avraham and Baer Heytev** there) understand that that **the first verse only is a Mitzva Deorayta**. This opinion is based on a couple of statements in Masechet Berachot 13b, a testimony that Rabbi Yehuda Hanasi was saying this verse only, Tanayim opinion supported by Amorayim ruled that this verse only needs Cavana, or needs full awareness.

. The **Rashba in Chiddushin** in first Chapter of Berachot regarding KS of bedtime and daf 21a , in name of Rabbi Shemaya, **Rabenu Yona**, understand that **the first chapter is Deorayta**. This opinion is based on several rules regarding first chapter of Shema which are based on verses (in the second chapter of Brachot 16a and in Yoma).

. **Some else** say that **the 3 first verses only are Deorayta**. The **Shaagat Arieh** holds this opinion.

. The **Pri Chaddash** in SA OC siman 67 summarizes the diverses opinion in Gemara and Poskim (he understands that Rambam's opinion (hilchot KS 1, 2) is that **2 parashiot are Deorayta** and holds this opinion. but the Shaagat Arieh siman 2 argues strongly against this lecture on Rambam.

. **Aruch Hashulchan** in siman OC 67 says that he rules, following his own understanding on Rambam that **the 3 parashiot are Deorayta**.

Comment: also tosfot menachot 43b

Comment: Ok I hope to read it thanks